# OpenLayers MousePosition control listening to position, using generic change event

Tags: openlayers, mouse-position

I want to add a MousePosition control, without using a HTML-control as target, but just put it in a variable.

```
    map.addControl(new ol.control.MousePosition({
        coordinateFormat: function(coordinate) {
            return ol.coordinate.format(coordinate, 'Lat: {y}, Long: {x}', 4);
        },
        className: 'coordinate_display',
        change: function(evt){
                 console.log(evt); //or anything to catch the event
                },
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    }));
```

Is it the right way to listen to the mousposition ? I dont get into to the change-handler.

Comment: You could use the map.on ('pointermove', ) event

Answer (score 1):

`ol.control.MousePosition` control has no `change` option (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_MousePosition-MousePosition.html), but you can 'misuse' `coordinateFormat` option function for your purpose.

Code could then look something like this:

```
map.addControl(new ol.control.MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: function(coordinate) {
    console.log(coordinte);  // displaying coordinate at each change
    return ol.coordinate.format(coordinate, 'Lat: {y}, Long: {x}', 4);
  },
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I found a solution like @mike mentioned. But thanks anyway:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659736/capturing-mousemove-for-a-single-layer-in-openlayers